# Should a subsection begin on the same page that another ends?

Tags: pages

I'm writing a textbook with multiple (potentially disjoint) sections in a chapter. Does it make more sense to break the section and start it on a new page, or just have it start from where the previous one ends? The latter looks cleaner but uses more pages (which isn't a huge issue). For reference, this is a computer science textbook.

Comment: The format should aid the reader in finding what they're looking for. I usually don't see 'sections' start on their own page, just a large header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fine to start a subsection on the same page.

The only thing I'd worry about is an "orphaned" sub-section, if the heading is the last thing on one page, and the first line is on the next page.

But looking for orphans is literally the last thing you should be checking for; because all editing and image moving and playing with margins and stuff like that can affect whether you end up with orphans.

And if you have to correct for orphans, do it in order, front to back, with one last editing pass. Because adding a /newpage page break, to force a section or subsection heading to the next page, can easily create new orphans after that, or even fix later orphans by doing that.

I have written academic papers but not a textbook. On an academic paper, I do look for orphans before submitting, but if I have to make corrections, even for just typos, and rewrite, add or delete text, or make an image larger, etc,  I comment out all my /newpage commands and repeat my search for image issues and then orphans from the start, before I submit my changes for further review.